# How To get size of varying cols in rows of a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you find the size of an individual row in a 2d matrice in which all the rows vary in size. So its not a NxM matrice rather they're all a little different in length.

```
vector<vector<int>> &someVector;
vector<int> v;
resV.resize(10);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (int)someVector.size(); j++) //iterates through all the rows
        if(!(someVector[i][j] <= 0) ) // i represents the row and j the col it is at
            .push_back(someVector[i][j]); // adds value into 1d vector
}
```

I used this code here because i know the columns length of 1 row wont exceed 10. It psuhes it into another vector which is of 1 row so it will be easier to print out and find its mid value which is something different that will be easy once i can get the values of this 2d vector into the 1d vector.

This code here results in an error on the 2nd for loop line.

Comment: You are probably looking for `someVector[i].size()`. For `someVector[i][j]` to be valid, `i` must be between 0 (inclusive) and `someVector.size()` (exclusive), while `j` must be between 0 (inclusive) and `someVector[i].size()` (exclusive)

Comment: this only gives me the column size. I am not looking for the column size as it stays constant. Rather i am looking for the row sizes which vary ex..

vector< vector<int> > v = { {2,3,52,5}, {2,42}, {43,63,63,6,2,3}, {12}  }

These all have different sizes of rows. I am looking for how to find their individual row sizes.

Comment: In your example, `v.size()` would be 4 (the number of braced groups within the outer braces), while `v[1].size()` would be 2 (the size of the second braced group). Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: sure, ill try this out and let you know.

Comment: Yea you were correct, my apologies I mixed them around. Thanks you for you help!